# Is an int with an enum range?

Tags: java, enums

Is there a way if I have an `int` to determine if it is within the ordinal range of an enum?
So that I can then safely do `theEnum.values()[ordinal];`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
if (yourInt >= 0 && yourInt < TheEnum.values().length) {
    // safe
}
```

Your `theEnum` should be the enum type, and not a variable of that enum type. I capitalized it to `TheEnum`, to follow the Java naming conventions.